# Password storage for use with symmetrical encrypt/decrypt

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption

I have a webforms application and need to store a password somewhere. The password will be used to encrypt/decrypt some other data in the system.

Seemingly my options are:

1. Database
2. Web.config
3. Constant in the assembly itself

I don't want it in the database for obvious security reasons and having it hard coded into an assembly is not great either.

So is my only option to place it in web.config in an encrypted section?

As the password will be used on multiple machines (Production / Test) I will then have the issue of managing keys for the encrypted web.config.

So I am hoping there is a simpler way to store a key securely that is not overkill. Has anyone got any suggestions>

Comment: This "password" is created by the user?

Comment: No it is a master password that is maintained by the developers.

Comment: Your software runs in a controlled environment (your infrastructure)? Or it is installed on a client's server?

Comment: Runs in the cloud so not strictly speaking our infrastructure but our VPS,

Comment: One last question. It is Microsoft Azure?

Comment: What do you think makes storing your key in a database (with appropriate access control) less secure than storing it in the assembly or on disk?

Comment: Encrypt the encrypted string and keep it in web.config. 
thats probably the only thing you can do which wont put a great overhead on your system. DB calls might be costly if you are frequently accessing it.

Comment: Guilherme - Nope not Azure.

Comment: @CollinDauphinee Coupe of reasons: SQL Injection could expose entire DB, DB Backups. It is inherently harder to get hold of source code and/or assemblies from a production system than it is DB data.

Comment: @WaqarAhmed And where do I store the password to DECRYPT the encrypted string stored in the web.config?

Comment: @TheEdge No need to store. For example : Use Base64 encoding within your app. encrypt the encrypted string and then save that string in your web.config. Later on when you need to use that encrypted string, decrypt the string with base64 decode method and do it whatever u want with it.

Comment: @WaqarAhmed Base64 has absolutely nothing to do with encryption... And OP already said that they are aware of proper storing secrets in Web.config - "only option to place it in web.config in an encrypted section" - so not sure what you comment adds.